# Display different results based on radio button selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a piece of JQuery to create the effect described at this website:

http://www.onextrapixel.com/2009/10/13/how-to-display-form-fields-based-on-selection-with-or-without-jquery-cookie/

What I need is to be able to display a different div based on the radio button selection.  I have been able to successfully implement what has been demonstrated on the site...however I can only do that for one selection.  I figure repeating the code, say 5 times, for 5 different divs would probably be really inefficient.
To keep things simple, I will probably name the divs the numbers 1-5.  Thanks so much for your help!

```
<fieldset>
<ol class="formset">
    <li><label for="fname1">First Name: </label>
<input type="text" id="fname1" value="" name="fname1"/></li>

    <li><label for="lname1">Last Name: </label>
<input type="text" id="lname1" value="" name="lname1"/></li>

    <li><label for="email1">Email Address: </label><br />
<input type="text" id="email1" value="" name="email1" /></li>

    <li><label for="age1">Are you above 21 yrs old?</label>
<input type="radio" name="age1" value="Yes" class="aboveage1" /> Yes
<input type="radio" name="age1" value="No" class="aboveage1" /> No
<input type="radio" name="age1" value="Maybe" class="aboveage1" /> Maybe
    </li>

</ol>
<ol id="parent1" class="formset">
<li><strong>Parent/Guardian Information:</strong></li>
    <li><label for="pname1">Parent Name: </label>
<input type="text" id="pname1" value="" name="pname1"/></li>
    <li><label for="contact1">Contact No.: </label>
<input type="text" id="contact1" value="" name="contact1"/></li>
</ol>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="submitbtn" />
</fieldset>
```

Current Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#parent1").css("display","none");
    $(".aboveage1").click(function() { 
        if ($('input[name=age1]:checked').val() == "No" ) {
            $("#parent1").slideDown("fast"); //Slide Down Effect 
        } 
        else {
            $("#parent1").slideUp("fast"); //Slide Up Effect 
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What code do you currently have?

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#parent1").css("display","none");
        $(".aboveage1").click(function(){
        if ($('input[name=age1]:checked').val() == "No" ) {
            $("#parent1").slideDown("fast"); //Slide Down Effect
        } else {
            $("#parent1").slideUp("fast");  //Slide Up Effect
        }
     });
});

Comment: @user791187 - Please edit your post and place any applicable code that you may have there.

Comment: No problem - we are all here to learn! So you have 5 divs. Will each div be shown/hidden by a different radio button? i.e. Div1 is shown/hidden by Radio1. Div2 shown/hidden by radio2 etc. Or are all 5 divs shown/hidden by a single radio group with 5 options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to slide down elements matching diferent answers to your aboveage and the divs have the same id as the answers values, you can do the following:

**Note:** You will have to rename your divs that correspond to the answers from formset to sub-formset in order to work.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('ol.sub-formset').css("display","none"); // display none on all ol that doesn't have formset class
    $('input[class^="aboveage"]').click(function() { 
        $('ol[class!="formset"]').slideUp("fast"); //Slide Up Effect 
        $('#' + $(this).val()).slideDown("fast"); //Slide Down Effect 
    });
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/L5qfn/

Comment: I am trying to only change the content that drops down.  lets say I have div1 that would display for "Yes" and div2 for "No" and div3 for "Maybe". Div2 and div3 would remain closed while Yes was selected.  Div2 would open and Div1 and Div3 would remain closed upon the "No" selection...and so forth.

Comment: Ok got it. I thought it was something like that site.

Comment: great, let me ask you this:  I am dynamically generating both the field value that corresponds to the div value.  I know I wont have more than say 20 entries.  I know the div that displays will be a number between 1 and 20.  Is it possible to form a loop through the values (1-20) and displays the corresponding div?

Comment: You can, but you have to create a way of relating the dynamic field to the dynamic div. Lets say a field with value No correspond to the div with value No too. If you want that I can help you come up with a solution.

Comment: Thats the way it is set up now...the radio value of age1 will be between 1 and 20...its coorisponding div has the same value.  How then would the javascript look to produce the effect?

Comment: I'll change my answer and post a jsfiddle so you can look at.

Comment: Please mark as a right answer if it helped you. Thanks. If not, we can try another thing.